Decomposition of an ideal in a Noetherian ring
Let $A$ be a commutative Noetherian ring. I want to prove that for any propre ideal $I$, there exist finitely many prime ideals $p_1, \ldots, p_n$ such that
$$
p_1 \cdots p_n \subset I \subset p_1 \cap p_2 \cap \cdots \cap p_n.
$$
I proved that $p_1 \cdots p_n \subset I$. We also have that $\sqrt{I} = q_1 \cap \cdots \cap q_s$ for some prime ideals $q_i$.
My question is how to prove that we can choose $p_i = q_i$.

Let $A$ be a commutative noetherian ring, and let $I$ be
a proper ideal.

Since $A$ is noetherian, we can express
$$
\sqrt{I}
=
\bigcap_{j=1}^m q_j
$$
as a finite intersection of prime ideals.

Since $\sqrt{I}$ is finitely generated, it follows that
$$
\left(
\sqrt{I}
\right)^k
\subseteq
I
$$
for some positive integer $k$.

Letting $n=km$, define the sequence $p_1,...,p_n$ by
$$
p_i=q_{{\large{\lceil i/k \rceil}}}
$$
Then we have
$$
I
\subseteq
\sqrt{I}
=
\bigcap_{j=1}^m q_j
=
\bigcap_{i=1}^n p_i
$$
and we also have
$$
\prod_{i=1}^n p_i
=
\left(
\prod_{j=1}^m q_j
\right)^k
\subseteq
\left(
\bigcap_{j=1}^m q_j
\right)^k
=
\left(
\sqrt{I}
\right)^k
\subseteq
I
$$
so the sequence $p_1,...,p_n$ satisfies the specified requirements.
